# keydown not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox4

```
 <script>
        function MoveNext(e, obj) {

            if (!e) var e = window.event;

            if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;

            else if (e.which) code = e.which;
            if (code == 13) {

                document.getElementById(obj).focus();

                return false;
            }
   </script>
```

the above code is working in IE but not in mozilla why

Comment: Can you provide more of the code involved in making this "work". How this is called for instance, can impact whether or not it works.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do? Do you get an error message? Have you been able to narrow down whether the problem is in the function body or in the way it is called, e.g., by replacing the function body with a single `alert("Test")` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the best code is for the return key depends upon which keyboard event you are listening to (keydown, keyup, keypress).  For keypress, you can do it like this:

```
function MoveNext(e, obj) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (code == 13) {
        document.getElementById(obj).focus();
    }
}
```

Note: I've remove your local variable `e` so it doesn't get confused with the argument `e` and I've defined `code` as a local variable which you had as an implicit global variable (never a good thing).

More on cross browser key handling described here: [keycode and charcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode).

Comment: I understand about hoisting in a general sense, but are you sure including `var e` overrides the parameter `e`? I don't do it in my own code, but I had an idea that attempts to redeclare a variable already defined in the current scope would be ignored, i.e., the extra `var` would be ignored.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yes, I am absolutely sure.  A local variable definition overrides an argument of the same name in the same way that the local variable overrides any variable of the same name in a higher scope (including globals).  See this working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LSSK9/.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but to clarify what I was trying to ask: if you have a function argument `e` followed by `var e` (without assigning a new value) should that result in `e` having the value `undefined` due to the variable hoisting behaviour shown in your answer? I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/LSSK9/1/ in IE and FF and the argument was unchanged so the alert said "foo". `if (!x) var x = 7;` also ended up alerting "foo".

Comment: @nnnnnn - I see what you're asking now.  That is a more tricky case that I am not sure about.  I don't know for sure how it works in all browsers.  I would certainly advise to never do it that way because  the programming desire is at best ambiguous.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yep, I certainly would never recommend it or do it myself - even if I was sure it worked in all browsers it is still misleading to read. I do use code similar to the if statement in the question except _without_ the offending `var`, i.e., `if (!e) e = window.event;`

Comment: I can't think of a reason to EVER define a local variable with the same name as a function argument.  You can always just assign directly to the argument variable (as I did in my answer) and be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
else if (e.which) code = e.which;
```

to

```
code = (e.keyCode)? e.keyCode: e.charCode;
```

and make sure your are passing your event to moveNext when you are calling it because firefox recognise event only if you sent it explicitly from the function.

also if your object that your are doing keydown is a div add to it a tabindex of 0 so it can retrieve focus .

```
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Even further simplifies to `code = e.keyCode || e.charCode;`