# JQuery click() and keyup() and IE9 Developer Tools issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I tried to load an html page with this JQuery script in IE9 Developer Tools (F12):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(this).click(function(event) {

        if ( $("#fancybox-overlay").is(":visible") ) {
            $("#panopano").show();
        }
        else if ( event.target.nodeName == "IMG" && event.pageY > 800 && event.pageY < 1500 ) {
            $("#panopano").hide();
        }

    });

    $(this).keyup(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#panopano").show();
        }

    });
    ...
```

These functions hide or show the krpano object, set by default with z-index: auto, causing problems with fancybox. Are these functions compatible with IE7 e IE8? Only with these two browser the html page load to infinity! No error in console. If I load the page with IE9 modality or with another browser, no problem.
I haven't considered IE6.

EDIT:
I modified the code (thank you @Imdad):

```
$(this).keyup(function(event) {

    var kCode;

    if ( event.keyCode )
    {
        kCode = event.keyCode;
    }
    else
    {
        kCode = event.charCode;
    }

    if (kCode == 27) {
        $("#panopano").show();
    }

});
```

Comment: Look at the post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode You can use `event.charCode` or `event.which` to be in safe.