# validation not working in Firefox but works in IE,Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I use the following java script function for integer validate which means the text box can allow to enter only the integer values alone.****It was work fine in Internet explorer and google chrome****.But I use this same function in FireFox the text box didn't allow to enter any characters in that which means it doesn't allow characters,numbers,space,anything else..How to solve this problem?

**javascript function**

```
$('.intValidate').live('keypress', function(event) {
                var integervalidate = intValidate(event);
                if (integervalidate == false)
                    return false;
            });

function intValidate(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||(event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||(event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39))
        {
            return;
        }
    else 
    {
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 ))
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
```

**I use the class like**,

```
  <input type="text" id="abcd" style="width:30px" maxlength="2"class="intValidate""/>
```

Comment: Did you try just changing it to `<input type="number" `...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the inconsistent way that browsers use the keypress event.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode) post to get a good explanation with an example of a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You're examining keycodes in the `keypress` event.  You should be looking at `charCode` values instead.