# Are Javascript char codes compatible with all or certain browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found the following code on the internet, when I saw this solution I wondered if this key code is the same for all browsers.

```
var CalendarFilter = Backbone.View.extend({
      // ...
      events: {
        'click .filter':  'filter',
        'keypress input[type=text]': 'filterOnEnter'
      },
      filterOnEnter: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        this.filter(e);
      },
      filter: function(e) { /* ... */ });
      }
    });
```

Just a doubt, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `charCode` is not `keyCode`! `charCode` follows the ascii set, while `keyCode` is a particular index of the key.. The different values between the two can be seen here: [Keyboard Event Character Values for the Lower ASCII Character Set - O'Reilly Answers](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/464-keyboard-event-character-values-for-the-lower-ascii-character-set/)

One major difference between `charCode` and `keyCode` is that [charCode is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.charCode) and typically has no value in some browsers [apart from 0] when referenced

Funnily enough, onkeypress seems to return the [character code instead of the `keyCode`](http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/events/default4.asp), while onkeyup and onkeydown works as expected, so there may be some issues when detecting `keyCode` values. You can test this out here [JavaScript - Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html#link7)
- Additional reference: [keyCode and charCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445228/1756941).

`keyCode`, `charCode` and `which` is [not recommended by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-key-attributes), however, there is still legacy support for the `keyCode` model. Solid cross browser/platform support is done with [fixed virtual keyCodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#fixed-virtual-key-codes) that stay independent of keyboard layout - hence being "virtual".

Other Virtual keyCodes - outside of the fixed virtual keyCodes - seems to be consistently implemented across vendors as well: [KeyboardEvent - Document Object Model (DOM) | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Virtual_key_codes) [Virtual-Key Codes (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

jQuery uses it's own `keyCode`/`charCode` event object property: `.which`, which attempts to unify `keyCode` and `charCode`. And favors `keyCode` values - [event.which – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

In short, your specific `keyCode`: "13", should work with most browsers that support javascript as it is a fixed virtual keycode and is consistent with all browsers and platforms

Answer (score 2):

The key codes are standard, but it might be best to check for key code `10` as well. `10` is the key code for "line feed", while `13` is the key code for "carriage return". There's a historical difference between the two (type writers needed to send both signals, a "line feed" to move the paper up and a "carriage return" to move the part that types over to the left side of the paper).

For instance, a quick check shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends keyCode `10` on Chrome on Windows. It's possible some 'nix systems use keyCode `10`, though I can't confirm. And a Google search reveals [iPhone may send 10](http://drupal.org/node/550360). There are likely other cases.

Some systems use one and some use the other to represent line breaks (last I checked, Windows uses a combination of both), but in the modern world they practically both mean <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so it wouldn't hurt to cover both bases.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. It's the same across the entire computer.

Answer (score 1):

The keyCode 13 (newline) has no issue with cross OS or cross Browser compatibility. No worries.