# event.keyCode returns the value of comma (188) for Turkish character "ö"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keycode

I have a Javascript function listening to **keydown** events and performs according to the key pressed.

My problem is as follows:

In **Chrome**, when I press "**ö**", which is a Turkish character with keyCode **246**, **event.keyCode** returns **188** which is the code of the comma (,) character. (Firefox returns 0 but this is not problem for me since it is different from the comma.)

So my question is how can I distinguish character "ö" from the comma in Chrome? Or is there a way to get the original keyCode 246 on keydown event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, in Chrome `"ö".charCodeAt(0)` returns 246? If you print the character to the console, is it a comma or the ö?

Comment: Why not use `event.charCode` on `keypress`?

Comment: `"ö".charCodeAt(0)` returns 246 for me also on Chrome v28.0.XX. Which Chrome version are you testing with? (ps.: Firefox 21.0 and 22.0 returns 246 also).

Comment: Definitive reading: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. You are confusing the code for the key (as in "keyboard") with the charCode from the character table.

Comment: I'm using Chromium version 18.0.1025.168 on Ubuntu 11.10. I know that the keypress event returns 246. However I have to handle the keydown event.

Comment: Did you find a solution?@ovunccetin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the ASCII code you have to listen to the `keypress` event and use `event.charCode`.

The `keydown` event does not provide the `charCode` since there is a little difference between these two event types:

> In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

[Source](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event.originalEvent.keyIdentifier` method. "ö" and comma has different keyIdentifiers.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445228/1823278) is a good answer for these kind of problems.
I see two rules here:

- to detect a character typed reliably, use keypress (with charCode)
- to detect non-printable characters such as arrows, use keydown (with keyCode)