# what is the meaning of this condition in java script?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is the meaning of this condition in java script?
How does it work?

```
function displayunicode(e){
    var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    alert(unicode)
}
```

Comment: give a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: That's known as `Ternary condition`. Elementary programming concept.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keycode and charcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `keypress` event in javascript you have this stuff, in some browsers you just have the `e.keyCode` in your event object, which here is `e`, and in some other browsers you have `e.charCode` instead. both `keyCode` and `charCode` refers to the key which is pressed.

and as @SB. has pointed out:

```
e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode
```

means exactly:

```
var unicode;
if (e.keyCode)
    unicode = e.keyCode
else
    unicode = e.charCode
```

and as I have said this piece of code wants to get the key which has been pressed in `keypress` event.

Comment: I think you have voted up, there is a sign below my votes part that you have to push if it is the answer, you were looking for

Answer (score 4):

Shorthand for:

```
var unicode;
if (e.keyCode)
   unicode = e.keyCode
else
   unicode = e.charCode

alert(unicode);
```

You can even write it as:

```
var unicode = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple inline if, have a look at this to understand how it works: [How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: This answer won't explain anything other than a link.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to write it in the comments but I didn't figure out later that was wrong place