# How to compare a key (which is either a keyCode or a charCode) with a string

Tags: javascript

When user presses a key, I want to check this key and compare it with the first letter of some string. if the key matches the first letter:
the text-field will be auto-completed with that string.

I have a function that gets the first key the user presses.

1. My problem is that I done't know how to compare this KEY (in my function I called it unicode) ,which is either a keycode or a charcode, with the first letter of my string.
2. the result in the text field is: the string+the key that was pressed rather then just the string.

this is my attempt so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<form>
user name: <input type = "text" id='name' onkeypress='completeFields(event);'> </br>
</form>

<script>

function completeFields(e){

var unicode;
if (e.keyCode)
    unicode = e.keyCode;
else
    unicode = e.charCode;

var username="shiran";
var chr1 = username.charAt(0);
var chr2 = unicode.toString().charAt(0);
  if(username!=null && username!="" && chr2==chr1){
        document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried String.fromCharCode() for the first question?

Comment: So i solved my first problem. does anyone have a suggestion how shall I delete the character(that the user pressed) from the text-field? and I cant use the keyup/keydown functions as they don't work with the KeyCode.

Comment: @Shiran: `document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";` is already doing that for you.

Comment: no it will print "shirans" .. it adds the character to the string... shiran+s..

Comment: I ll open a new question for that with a ready example

Comment: @Shiran: Yes, I missed that. I have updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: thank you very much..ll look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need: `String.fromCharCode()`

```
var ch = String.fromCharCode(unicode);
var chr1 = username.charAt(0);
if(username!=null && username!="" && ch==chr1){
    document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";
}
```

Using keycode and/or charcode with keypress is explained here: [keycode and charcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode)

Regarding your second question about deleting the user entered character, the statement `document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";` is already doing that.

**Update**:

Yes, actually `document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";` can't do the trimming. This is because you are capturing the `keypress` which means the character is not assigned to the `value` property until `keyup` happens.

So, now you need to trap the `keyup` event.

Have a variable in appropriate global scope and make it false. Once, `keypress` is evaluated successfully, make it true. Then on `keyup` check if it was true and chop off the last character. Note: I am saying global scope here only as an example. Ideally you would put in appropriate scope.

*globals*:

```
var done = false;
```

*onkeypress*:

```
var ch = String.fromCharCode(unicode);
var chr1 = username.charAt(0);
if(username!=null && username!="" && ch==chr1){
    document.getElementById("name").value="shiran";
    done = true;
} else {
  done = false;
}
```

*onkeyup*:

```
if (done) {
    var currentValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
      document.getElementById("name").value = currentValue.value.slice(0, - 1);
}
```

Comment: @Shiran: this will help you understand it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode

Comment: Working fine at my end. There is a missing opening brace just after the `else` in your key press function.

Comment: this is the error it shows :" "TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefinedat deleteLast  ". I didn't find any open brace..

Comment: Ok. It's past midnight here. Will get back in morning. Hope you can wait. I can't check as I am on mobile.

Comment: first of all thank you very much for looking at it at this time.. I ll have to complete it within 4 hours.. so I hope I ll find the solution by myself.. I ll let you know. :-)

Comment: @Shiran: found the problem. you have an extra `value` there. change `currentValue.Value.slice(0, - 1);` to `currentValue.slice(0, - 1);`