# Need the function to be triggered on hit of enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search box whch is a text type. it has a click button, which initiates the Find().

how can i do the find by hitting enter inside the textbox

Comment: is the input in a form element?

Answer (score 2):

If your text input is inside of a form element, you can attach an onSubmit (or jQuery .submit()) event handler to the form element. This event will fire when the user presses enter while inside the text input

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-keypress`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress) on the `input` element and check for `enter` key code:

```
<input type="text" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13) ? Find() : void(0)" />
```

This is assuming that `jQuery` has been loaded. Otherwise, you might want to use `$event.keyCode`, but doing it in a browser compatible way [would be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445228/987185).

---

If you have a directive which contains this template, then you should catch this event in the `link` function and call `Find` there. Otherwise, putting the `input` button inside a `form` and defining a `on-submit` on the `form` element. Do check for IE compatibility though, I remember IE7 at least needs a hidden `<input type="submit" />` in the form for the enter key to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {//when key is pressed

        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (13 == evt.keyCode) {//if key was enter
            if (document.activeElement.className== "search_input"){//if the focus is on your input (in this case search_input)
                Find() //call your function
                return false;//cancel enter
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally have very good luck with Angular-UI. The ui-keypress directive should serve well in this case. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/keypress. The keycode you want for the Return/Enter key is 13.