# wrong ASCII key code for delete key

Tags: javascript, ascii, keycode

I have an HTML form in which I need to allow only numeric key-press. For this i have used the following code

```
    $(".span8").keypress(function(e) 
    {
         var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
     //alert(unicode);
     if ((unicode ==8) || (unicode==9)|| (unicode==46)){
        //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
     }
     else
     {
         if (unicode<48||unicode>57&&unicode!=65) //if not a number
         return false //disable key press
     }
```

`});`

but here if I am testing keycode, I am getting value as 46 for delete key. 46 is for dot(- period)
Others values are coming correct. I am not able to find were am I going wrong. 
Please help

Comment: check this : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml

Comment: thanks @Sasi. The code helped me!!!

Answer (score 5):

I've found this weird behaviour too with the `keypress` function.

Instead, try the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var input = $('.span8');
  input.on('keydown', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if(key == 8 || key == 46)
        //Do something when DEL or Backspace is pressed
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakob,,, Using keydown sorted my issue actually. But why do keydown and keypress produces different results??

Comment: I've explained this [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18864466/2518317) and another also [makes reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445228/2518317) as to why the values are different