# Allow some special character like dash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript to disallow user to use special character in textbox. But I want to allow user to use dash (-) in textbox. Kindly update my function.

To Dis Allow user to use special character

```
 function alpha(e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
        }
```

Allow only numbers

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
              && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;

            return true;
```

What is the keycode to allow use to use dash (-) in 1st function ?

Comment: Do a console.log{charCode); before the if and press the dash key.

Comment: `document.all ?` Really? Haven't see that in years!! Consider `var k = e.keyCode || e.which` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a javascript keyCode list: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.

Dash KeyCode is 189(- from keyboard) or 109(- [minus sign - subtract from keypad]).

Dash has a CharCode of 45.

Here is a description of what KeyCode & CharCode means: [keycode and charcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode)

And here you can test keydown, keypress, keyup events. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

So if you're applying your alpha function on keydown event, you must change it accordingly:

```
function alpha(e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            // UPDATED - is CHARCODE
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57) || k == 45);
        }
```

Depends if you want minus or dash or just one of them.

Comment: I want to allow users to use any of from minus and dash. but your query in not working

Comment: Check only for charcode 45. I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm happy that i can help you. It always depends what event are you listening to (keyup/keydown or keypress) and if you look at keycode or charcode.

Answer (score 0):

Dash key code is 189.

But your code is harder to maintain with char codes, you should consider using named constants in place of numbers.