# Javascript regex for numbers only is accepting # $ % & (

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to regex an input field in javascript. 
What I do is, eveytime a key is pressed, the following code is being called:

```
function testPattern(pattern, evt) {
    // in this case, pattern = "^[0-9]*$"
    var inputField = evt.getCurrentTarget();
    var keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    var oldValue = inputField.getSubmittedValue();

    // return if keycode is navigation, delete or backspace
    if((keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46){
        return;
    }

    var regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    var hasMatch = false;

    hasMatch = regExp.test(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));

    if (!hasMatch) {
        inputField.setValue(oldValue);
        evt.cancel();
    }
}
```

The expected result is: no character is written in the input text box if the input is different from a digit.
It is working fine, except for the characters **# $ % &** and **(**

I've tried the following regex (very similar)

```
"^[\\d]$"
"^[\\d]*$"
"^[\\d]+$"
"^[0-9]*$"
```

Does someone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your regexps.

The problem is in

```
// return if keycode is navigation, delete or backspace
if((keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40) || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46)
    return;
```

If you have a look at an ascii table you will see that:

```
8     backspace
35    #
36    $
37    %
38    &
39    ´
40    (
46    .
```

Your problem comes from a confusion between keyCode and charCode in the browser implement / keyboard event that you are listening to:

This question might be a good read: [keycode and charcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444477/keycode-and-charcode)

Comment: That was supposed to ignore arrow navigation, and character deletions. I thought that would be Char Codes http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes . Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

use the regex in this way:

```
/^\d+$/
```

Comment: It still happens.. This behaves exactly like the ones I've used. I think it's a really weird behaviour..

Answer (score 0):

Restrict this ASCII 35,36,37,38,39,40 to restrict those symbols or you can use below mentioned code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
    specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
    specialKeys.push(36); //Home
    specialKeys.push(35); //End
    specialKeys.push(37); //Left
    specialKeys.push(39); //Right

    function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 32 && keyCode <= 32)||(keyCode >= 44 && keyCode <= 44)||(keyCode >= 46 && keyCode <= 46)||(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```