# keyCode or which not working when using selection:cleared in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using `fabric js` and created designer where user can design objects and delete that objects.

But for some reason, user not able to delete object because of this event

```
before:selection:cleared
```

So, now i want to detect which key user pressed, so for that what i did is

```
canvas.on('before:selection:cleared', function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    console.log(e.which);
    if(typeof(canvas.getActiveObject()) !== 'undefined') {
                if(jQ.isEmptyObject(previous_object)){
                }else{
                    previous_object.moveTo(prev_pos);
                    previous_object={};
                    prev_pos='';
                }
                loadLayers();
            }
});
```

But it returns undefined. Is there any other solution to detect key?

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445228/2006429).

Comment: `charCode` also returns undefined @usandfriends. any solution?

Comment: yes, i created object of canvas and then i want to do some things when `selection:cleared` so i used this event of canvas.

Comment: Wait a minute... `before:selection:cleared` fires when a user selects another object. Why do you think that event will give you a __key__ code? Selecting = clicking. Also, why would that event have anything to do with __deleting__ objects?

Comment: actually `delete` is working proper before i used this event. i am doing this `var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        
        canvas.remove(obj);` to remove object, but after click on delete. it automatically calls `before:selection:cleared` event, and i have some code in this event. i updated that in question. which not allow to delete or may be deleting then generating new object again? as i used `moveto`?